# How can I unblock my IP address for outlook.com?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap, hotmail

I have a couple of outlook accounts which I often access from foreign IP addresses. As a consequence, my access was blocked (there is no way to turn off this feature, it seems). After verifying my identity I went to the "confirm recent activity" page and confirmed that all of the attempts from other IP addresses were mine.

Yet, I still cannot log on on the blocked devices. I can sign in online, and access via IMAP from my desktop mail program, but IMAP access from the other devices remains blocked even after confirming my recent identity.

Is there any way that I can bypass this block?

Answer (score 1):

To remove your IP from the Hotmail/Outlook blacklist, you could try to submit a request to Hotmail by following this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportrequestform/8ad563e3-288e-2a61-8122-3ba03d6b8d75 and wait for a response from hotmail.